# What is difference between the gateway in ifcfg-ens192 and the one print by route

Tags: linux, networking, route, gateway

when i cat the file

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192
```

a line showing the gateway for ens192:

```
GATEWAY=10.2.2.2
```

but when i run  netstat -r or route

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens192
10.2.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens192
10.2.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens256
```

Gateway seems to be 0.0.0.0
what is the difference between the two gateway?
i am so confused..

Comment: Is there another line in netstat's output that includes 10.2.2.2 ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick No, there isnt, ive edit to the full netstat output

Comment: Can you add `-n` to the `netstat -r` command?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick, the n flag shows gateway as 10.2.2.2! thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand the meaning of a gateway. You need a gateway for reaching an IP address which is not link-local.

`10.2.2.0/255.255.255.0` **is** link-local thus you do not need a gateway for it. This entry does not show which gateway is used but which interface is used for this subnet.

Comment: so 10.2.2.2 should not appear in route or netstat -r?

Comment: @once I am not so familiar with `route`, I always use `ip route`. I would expect your line `default gateway` to be `default 10.2.2.2`. Maybe your entry `GATEWAY=10.2.2.2` is wrong somehow and thus not accepted as default gateway.